# strip url for file_put_contents php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a script that is parsing an XML file. It needs to save the images referenced in the file to the local server. The problem I have is it is trying to save the images as the full url path which results in a http error. Here is the XML that matters:

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents(''.$target_file_path.'');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);
$items = $xml->xpath('//image1/@src');
foreach($items as $item) {
$content = file_get_contents(''.$url.''.$item.'');
file_put_contents(''.$images_folder_path.''.$item.'', $content);
```

I need to strip the url stored in $item leaving just image.jpg between file_get_contents and file_put_contents, any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The XML Input is:

```
<time>13:12</time>
<date>02/15/13 </date>
<image1 src="http://path/to/image.jpeg" height="180" width="144" style="border-color: #800000" border="1" />
```

The images are stored remotely and I need to copy them to the local server, as the full url is stored in the "item" variable when the script gets to file_put_contents is is trying to save the file as

```
/home/server/public_html/folder/http://path/to/image.jpeg
```

Comment: Try using 'basename()' this will strip the path information and only leave the file name

Comment: Could you post an example `<image1>` tag too? I'm not sure that i understand what your input is.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
basename("http://www.example.com/picture.jpg");
```

It will output `picture.jpg`

Comment: Any ideas about how to strip this from the variable $item before file_put_contents